# jQuery data-* vs class selector - performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, performance-testing

I've seen many examples(including favorite Twitter's bootstrap) where various APIs make use of `$("[data-something]")` rather than selecting by class `$(".something")`

Nethertheless I tried to find information about performance between these two different selectors. I was surprised that many performance test did find out that those selectors are equally fast on most of the modern browsers so I decided to do [my own test](http://jsperf.com/class-vs-data-test)

I'm really confused right now and I don't know if it's my test that are done wrong(somehow?) or is it other tests that I inspected before?

Could anybody provide more information if I'm doing something wrong while testing or are these test correct and **data-attribute** selector IS in fact pretty much slower than regular **class** selector?

Thank you

Comment: I think is because `data-attribute` uses either `querySelectorAll` or sizzle if needed, while a regular class uses the faster `getElementsByClassName`. Check http://jsperf.com/class-vs-data-1

Comment: Well I understand that, but as I read before I was surprised to find that some test show equal performance for both selectors that's why I did my own test and now I want some confirmation are those test correct. Or maybe someone can point I out what I did wrong :)

Comment: I'd say yes, those results seem correct to me. It's trivial though, unless you have like a thousand elements...

Comment: I believe with thousand, or any other big number, elements results should be worse for data-attribute selector, because the DOM would be even bigger for searching right elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/are-data-attribute-css-selectors-faster-than-class-selectors

Answer (score 6):

When using attribute selectors, performance may vary depending on querySelector support in your browser. jQuery will fall back to a built-in library (called SizzleJS) which is a lot slower.

Selection on class names will be faster because it will always use getElementsByClassName which is commonly supported on all common browsers.

The way I see it, classes serve a different purpose then data attributes. Classes will "categorize" elements so they can be styled properly and create structure.

Data attributes are exactly that: data. Sometimes you need to store additional data in your elements. For instance:

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="4" data-category="1">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I'm not using the regular "id" attribute because of the same reason.