# jquery game of life detect neighbour cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently working on a little jquery project. I want to build Conway's game of life with javascript/jquery/html. But I can't figure out, how to detect if a cell has alive neighbours. But I know I have to make use of Arrays.

Here what I came up with so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $create_grid = $('#create_grid');
var $run = $('#run');
var $reset = $('#reset');
var $random = $('#random');
var $cells = {};
var $active_cells = {};

$create_grid.click(function () {

    var width = $("[name='width']").val();
    var height = $("[name='height']").val();
    var cellsize = $("[name='cellsize']").val();
    var $table = $('#game');

    if (width.length != 0 && height.length != 0 && cellsize.length != 0) {

        for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            $('table').append('<tr id="' + i + '"></tr>');
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
            $('table tr').append('<td class="test" id="' + i + '"></td>');
        }
        $cells = $('table#game td');

        $cells.css('width', cellsize);
        $cells.css('height', cellsize);

    } else { alert("Please fill out all the fields!"); }

    $create_grid.hide('fast');
    $('ul.parameters').hide('fast');
    $random.css('display', 'block');
    $reset.css('display', 'block');

    //RESET CELLS
    $reset.click(function () {
        $cells.removeClass('alive');
    });

    //DRAW CELLS
    var isDown = false;

    $cells.mousedown(function () {
        isDown = true;
    })
        .mouseup(function () {
            isDown = false;
        });

    $cells.mouseover(function () {
        if (isDown) {
            $(this).toggleClass('alive');
        }
    });

    $cells.click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('alive');
    });
});

//RANDOM PATTERN
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
    return array;
}

$random.click(function () {
    $(shuffle($cells).slice(0, 30)).addClass("alive");
});


//RUN SIMULATION
$run.click(function simulate() {


    //GET NEIGHBOUR CELLS
    $cells_alive = $('#game td.alive').length;


    for (var c = 1; c <= $cells_alive; c++) {

            alert(c);


        };

});
```

});

Comment: Best way to approach this in my opinion would be to make a cell-object with some additional data (coordinates of where it lives in the grid) and functions (getNeighbors for example). It seems that you're trying to find a dom-driven solution which is not the easiest way to go. Your DOM is just for presentation, the logic should just manipulate the data. A simple array makes it very hard to find your neighbors indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your assigned ids are not unique. All rows and all columns have ids from `1..n` respectively `1..m`. So every number from `1..min(n,m)` is used twice. You should change this.

You might also want to assign some classes or data-attributes or just anything which makes it possible to actually select any of the html elements you create.

This for example sets some data-attributes to all `tr` and `td` tags.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        var elem = $('<tr></tr>');
        elem.data('column', i);
        $('table').append(elem);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
        var elem = $('<td></td>');
        elem.data('row', i);
        $('table tr').append();
    }
    $cells = $('table#game td');

    $cells.css('width', cellsize);
    $cells.css('height', cellsize);
```

If you have coordinates `(x, y)` you may select all neighbors like

```
$('tr[data-column='+(x-1)+'] td[data-row='+y+'], 
   tr[data-column='+(x+1)+'] td[data-row='+y+'], 
   tr[data-column='+x+'] td[data-row='+(y-1)+'], 
   tr[data-column='+x+'] td[data-row='+(y+1)+']');
```

(You might want to consider `class` instead for efficiency reasons. Although I do not know if this makes a notable difference.)

**EDIT:**

Here's a question about the performance of `data-` vs `class` selectors: [Are data attribute css selectors faster than class selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/are-data-attribute-css-selectors-faster-than-class-selectors)