# Why am I able to select an element by class more quickly than by data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a small jsperf to test selecting an element with jQuery: http://jsperf.com/testing-class-selector-vs-data-selector2

I found the results to be shocking. It says that it is 80% slower to use:

```
var foo = $('[data-ui=foo]');
```

versus

```
var foo = $('.ui-foo');
```

Shouldn't these be equally as performant? Both looking for an exact match on a string inside of a specific area of the DOM either in 'class' or 'data-ui'?

Comment: I think browsers handle classes (and ids) differently because they're used for css.

Comment: I think the first method is just outdatted.

Comment: For reference: https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/are-data-attribute-css-selectors-faster-than-class-selectors

Comment: It's obvious but it's actually dependant on browser implementation (try those selectors on an older IE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
var foo = $('[data-ui=foo]');
```

scans the whole DOM tree but this

```
var foo = $('.ui-foo');
```

simply returns list of elements of that class. Usually browsers maintain collection of elements under each class. For optimization purposes.This collection gets populated once per DOM parsing time (and class attribute updates).

Comment: That makes sense. I am struggling with conflicting desires though. If I'm only using the class to be able to select the element via JavaScript then I feel like it's more semantic to use a custom data attribute. To me, classes are for decorating with CSS.

Is there any merit to using a data attribute if it's just hands-down slower and I can achieve the same functionality with a prefixed class?

Comment: @c-smile, your statements seems reasonable. Do you have any sources to corroborate them?

Comment: You can achieve almost the same speed if you will cache results of your request. But you will need a mechanism of invalidation of that cache when DOM changes.  If your DOM is dynamic of course.

Comment: @lagerone  There are methods like `document.getElementsByClassName` , `document.getElementsByName` that are optimized historically as they were the only methods to query DOM trees. I wouldn't insist that they have to use caching but the caching is probably the most popular way of dealing with `O(N)` problems.