# Are there any performance (or otherwise) differences concerning attributes vs. classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm curious about adding classes vs. adding attributes to elements in order to dynamically style them.

The convention for applying CSS properties to certain elements that satisfy specific parameters is usually done by applying a class to that element. For instance if I click on a button, that button can be said to be in an active state - I could choose then to apply a custom class to it on click, like so:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

The CSS would be as simple as:

```
.button.active {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

My approach is different, and I'm curious as to whether there's any appreciable difference between the two. I apply attributes to the elements instead of classes, like so:

```
 $(".button").click(function(){
     $(this).attr("active", true);
 });
```

With the CSS like this:

```
.button[active] {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

I'm wondering if there are any reasons why I *shouldn't* do this i.e. if this is a bad convention or whatever and if there's any performance difference in this method. Mostly just curious, but also wondering if using queries like `$(".button[active]")` turn out to be less performant than `$(".button .active")`, for example.

Comment: For what it's worth: `active` isn't a valid HTML attribute. You'd need to use `data-active` instead. Furthermore, `.button .active` selects the `.active` child of `.button`, whereas `.button[active]` selects the `.button` element with the attribute `active` - you'd need to use `.button [active]`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I see! So I can't just use custom attribute names willy nilly? Oh my mistake! I'll correct it

Comment: class _is an attribute_ of the HTML element

Comment: @Zimmi they're accessed differently on the JavaScript side, though.

Comment: @Zimmi This is why I ask! I'm curious to know, for instance, if using a jquery attribute selector is less performant

Comment: You generally can get away with custom attribute names (every browser should handle them fine), but HTML validators will yell at you, so it's just good practice to follow the standard of putting `data-` in front of the attributes. It ensures that none of your attributes will ever end up causing something weird to happen (i.e. Suppose you use the "active" attribute, and in the future, an "active" attribute is added to the html spec. Suddenly your "active" attribute might have some weird side effect.) and lets you easily see which attributes are your custom ones.

Comment: @oxguy3 Expertly explained, thanks for the clarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone created a performance test for an answer to a  [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/are-data-attribute-css-selectors-faster-than-class-selectors) stack overflow question.

http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Looks like class selectors are much faster than attribute selectors, though apparently the amount changes depending on the browser.

Comment: Wow, I ran the test and attributes showed a *99% slower score* than using class selectors!

Comment: In case that link goes down, here are the results my browser generated (I'm using Chrome 43.0.2357.130 on Fedora 22 64-bit). IDs are 1,458,439 ops/sec, tags are 762,970 ops/sec, classes are 506,035 ops/sec, attributes are 23,342 ops/sec, pseudo-selectors are 992 ops/sec (wow that's crazy slow). So you can only do about 4.6 attribute matches in the same time you can do 100 class matches (source: 23,342/506,035=0.046). That's a huuuge difference, didn't expect that.

Comment: I altered the test a bit to use native stuff instead of jQuery. https://jsperf.com/byid-byclass-byattribute

Answer (score 4):

Mozillas [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) tl;dr for this:

1. attribute selectors are *universal* selectors

> **Universal rules**
>
> All other rules fall into this category.
>
> *Example*
>
> ```
> [hidden="true"] {…} /* A universal rule */`
> * {…}     /* A universal rule */
> tree > [collapsed="true"] {…} /* A universal rule */
> ```

2. Don't use universal selectors.

> **Avoid universal rules**
>
> Make sure a rule doesn’t end up in the universal category!

But there is [active](http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/) [discussion](https://smacss.com/book/selectors) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/) [css](http://jsperf.com/data-selector-performance) [selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/).

Most interestingly, CSSLint considers [disallowing unqualified attribute selectors](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-unqualified-attribute-selectors) for performance reasons.

*I would therefore stick to class selectors which have shown to be performant (when, as always, not misused ;) )*.